# Laravel + JWT Authentication not working on my side

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, laravel-5.3

am following up [This](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-and-angularjs-token-based-auth-part1/) tutorial to learn the jwt cool stuff. but when am testing the first bit of the server API with POSTMAN only the `id`,`password` fields are the one being inserted in the database. When I try to login with POSTMAN I get

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: from the server preview
```

my routes

```
Route::post('api/register', 'TokenAuthController@register');
Route::post('api/authenticate', 'TokenAuthController@authenticate');
Route::get('api/authenticate/user', 'TokenAuthController@getAuthenticatedUser');
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class TokenAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }

    public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {

            if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
            }

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

        }

        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $newuser = $request->all();
        $password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

        $newuser['password'] = $password;

        return User::create($newuser);
    }
}
```

I don't know where am messing out this code.

Comment: Do you send a post request for login or it's get?

Comment: Its a post request I send to authenticate